# C# SqlConnections using up entire connection pool

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlconnection

I've written a service that occasionally has to poll a database very often. Usually I'd create a new `SqlConnection` with the `SqlDataAdapter` and fire away like this:

```
var table = new DataTable();

using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectStatement, connection))
    {
        adapter.Fill(table);
    }
}
```

However in a heavy load situation (which occurs maybe once a week), the service might actually use up the entire connection pool and the service records the following exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.   This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Multiple threads in the service have to access the SQL server for various queries and I'd like as much of them to run in parallel as possible (and that obviously works too well sometimes).

I thought about several possible solutions:

- I thought about increasing the connection pool size, however that might just delay the problem.
- Then I thought about using a single connection for the service and keep that open for the remainder of the service running, which might a simple option, however it will keep the connection open even if there is no workload to be done and would have to handle connection resets by the server etc. which I do not know the effect of.
- Lastly I thought about implementing my own kind of pool that manages the number of concurrent connections and keeps the threads on hold until there is a free slot.

What would be the recommended procedure or is there a best practice way of handling this?

Comment: First, double- and triple- check that you're not leaking connections somewhere. Then run SQL profiler and establish whether you genuinely have multiple *long running* queries.

Comment: All connections are wrapped with `using`. The bottleneck is the SQL server in that case. It happens when both the service has a lot of work to do and simultaneously someone is running a long blocking query on the SQL Server. It's actually not so much the service's queries taking too long but another query causing a deadlock on the SQL Server. The problem is, I can't avoid these deadlocking queries because the original DB programmer... let's say I'd have some words for him I'd rather not write down. So I have to wait for the server to solve the deadlock for me...

Comment: [Here's a blog post from over a decade ago](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/angelsb/2004/08/25/connection-pooling-and-the-timeout-expired-exception-faq/) where essentially two of your ideas are covered in the "bad ideas" solution section. (Increasing pool size and setting massive timeout)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah well, they didn't feel right the moment I wrote them down. So I'm stuck with the last one?

Comment: Is your service running the same query all the time? Btw, what exactly do you mean by service? How long does this query take to execute? How likely the dataset it returns is to change?

Comment: Or with fixing the real problem. Deadlocks aren't a fact of life. They're a problem to be fixed, not something to be papered over.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever as I said, it's down to the original DB programmer. Short of re-writing the whole database - which is at least a one year job (which I'd like to do, the company however doesn't) - the only way is to work around it.

Comment: @hazimdikenli The service processes a batch of requests to generate documents. So it is just 2 selects to get the data then it gets processed and 2 updates to write back job completion each taking less than 100ms. If there's no blocking query on the database I can run more than 500 jobs in parallel and it doesn't even flinch.

Comment: What work is the long-running blocking query doing?  I'm assuming it's writing data?  Can that one be restructured into (for example) a stored procedure which builds the results in-memory (table variable) and then does the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` in one hit, locking the database for a shorter time?

Comment: Also, are they actually "deadlocking", or are the `SELECT` queries just being blocked for a long time by the "long-running query"?

Comment: Is it possible to use a dataset to pull data at once, so 1 select instead of 2. Likewise using a dataset again to post changes so 1 commit instead of 2. It is possible technically but I don't know your table relations, so this might not be possible in your case. It might help overall by keeping the connections less open, and you would do half the number of Open and Close operations on the server.

Comment: Sounds like you need a Message Queuing system, I am afraid this might degrade performance per tick, but your service would be more reliable.

Comment: @Trevor it's actually two queries (that have nothing to do with me) deadlocking each other for up to 300 (!) seconds and my `SELECT`/`UPDATE` queries are just being blocked.

Comment: For the `SELECT`s, have you considered changing the `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` on your connections to read past the table/row locks?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql

Comment: Deadlocks don't last for a period of time, hence the term (neither process can proceed as it is dependant on the other completing); blocking is what you are experiencing. Unless of course the deadlock timeout is 300 seconds (which I don't think even exists in SQL server)

Comment: @Charleh it's actually a bit of both blocking an deadlocking. SQL Server very definitely kills a deadlocked query in `SNAPSHOT` mode. These deadlocks then of course are perfectly capable of blocking other requests that will resolve once the deadlocked session has been killed.

Comment: Yes you are right, and that deadlock lasts a relatively long time (5 seconds at the most), then subsequent deadlocks are checked for and detected faster. However it makes sense in your case if you are eating up as many connections as possible in order to process a parallel workload that you'd starve the connection pool having to wait 5 seconds before the first connection returned instead of 100ms. Fun stuff (more fun than what I'm working on!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution in the end was not exactly ideal (fixing the issue on the SQL Server side) so I ended up checking the number of concurrent connections in the job queuing system.

The service will now not create another thread for document generation unless it can guarantee that the connection pool is actually available. The bad bottleneck on the SQL server is still in place, however the service now no longer generates exceptions.

The downside of course is, that the queue gets longer while there is some blocking query executing on the SQL Server, which might delay document generation for a minute or two. So it isn't an ideal solution but a workable one, since the delay isn't critical as the documents aren't needed directly but stored for archival purpose.

The better solution would have been to fix it SQL Server side.